# How to update json data from query after serialize?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model which have a `ForeignKey` field.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    # more fields
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.TextField()

class FessapComment(models.Model):
    # more fields
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
```

And on views, I do a `filter` query.

```
comments = FessapComment.objects.filter(fessap_id=fessap_id)
```

And serializing.

```
json_data = serializers.serialize('json', comments)
return JsonResponse(json_data, safe=False)
```

As we now, here's the json look likes:

```
"[
{
    "fields": 
        {
            "timestamp": "2016-05-06T13:39:46.584Z",
            "client": "U2B3DBDC",
        },
    "model": "socmed.fessapcomment", 
    "pk": 1
},
{
    "fields": 
        {
            "timestamp": "2016-05-06T15:23:12.641Z",
            "client": "U26A6E19",
        },
    "model": "socmed.fessapcomment", 
    "pk": 2
}
]"
```

It's looks not cool because it just return `id` of `client`, I can't call the `name` and `address` of `client`. So how to update that json in order to looks like this:

```
"[
{
    "fields": 
        {
            "timestamp": "2016-05-06T13:39:46.584Z",
            "client": 
                {
                    "id": "U2B3DBDC",
                    "name": "Herman James",
                    "address": "Uooepi St.",
                },
        },
    "model": "socmed.fessapcomment", 
    "pk": 1
},
{
    "fields": 
        {
            "timestamp": "2016-05-06T15:23:12.641Z",
            "client": 
                {
                    "id": "U26A6E19",
                    "name": "Jared",
                    "address": "Ter St.",
                },
        },
    "model": "socmed.fessapcomment", 
    "pk": 2
}
]"
```

Or there's another way to call `name` and `address` of `client` in template?

Thank you very much for your answer...

Comment: What do you want to do with the serialized data? Is it for an API of some sort or for data export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has [Natural Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/#natural-keys). Take a look at this.